# how strong is 4x6 Pressure Treated wood laid flat on top of drain rock?

Tags: pressure

I'm in the process of building a 60'x12' bocce ball court and need to create the borders. I'm debating between using 4x6 PT, stacked two tall on its widest side, or using 6x6.

the layers would be as such: 4" compacted drain rock, drain rock fabric, 4x6 PT with another 4x6 PT over it to have the height be a total of 7" on top of the drain rock. on top of this and on the inside of the bocce ball court would be heart redwood just for cosmetic purposes. the top part would be 2x8 redwood and the inside bumper 2x6 vertically. once finished, i would fill the first inch of the court with base rock, followed by 3" of decomposed granite.

would two 4x6 stacked on top of each other over the length and sides of the court be strong enough to withstand stepping on it, as well as not twist? I plan to secure the two 4x6's to each other with construction adhesive and also Spax or GRK 5 5/8 screws every foot or two. the corners would overlap and  i'd also drive some rebar every 7 feet or so along the entire length to hold it to the ground

i'm concerned with the PT flexing as you step on it and also twisting over time.

thanks!

Comment: Two 4x6, glued and screwed together to make an 8x6 are going to be very strong (and _painfully_ expensive at today's insane prices). The key to long term durability will be the base. You'll want it to be very firmly compacted so it doesn't settle, as the wood will eventually sag into any low spots in the stone base. Twisting can be highly _resisted_ (but not 100% _prevented_) by having the growth rings of the 4x6s facing in opposite directions as much as possible.

Comment: As advised by FreeMan, compaction is the key. But I wonder if the glue and nailing are necessary if you can bolt it down every 4' or so.

Answer (score 1):

Where I live this is a standard way of building short retaining walls for small garden plots.  1/2" or 5/8" rebar at least 2 feet into the ground every 3/4 feet.  pack the gravel and if it's deep you may need longer rebar.  Large drain rock can be very hard to pound through.  Usually it's not necessary, but you can put a point on the rebar by cutting it with an angle grinder.  Pre drill the wood ties with an augur bit for a good pressure fit.

Answer (score 0):

I built a balasted railing system on a roof deck using a single border of 4x8pt.  I let the wood naturally weather for 6 months before putting the outline together.  The longest pieces were 26' and the longest sections were 40'.  Allowing it to naturally weather let me pick the straightest pieces and cut the warped pieces for smaller sections of my outline.  Some of the 4x8 warped / twisted but most stayed relatively straight.  My 4x8s are not secured downward to anything.  I used 1/4" galvanized steel plates with #8 acq screws to hold the pieces together.  Where the 4x8pt boarder turned corners I used 10" grk screws or 3/8" galvanized lag screws.  I've had it assembled this way for a couple years now and it is all still great.

Your plan can definitely work with KH's approach pinning the 4x8pt downward every 4 feet with rebar stakes.  I'd just do the one layer given the cost.